# What is the real purpose of operator== for a std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, operators, comparison-operators, nullptr

I've seen the `operator==` of a `std::function` misused more than once and I've had to explain what is its real use.
For the sake of clarity in favor of future readers, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_cmp) is the documentation.
The documentation above mentioned says that it:

> Compares a std::function with a null pointer. Empty functions (that is, functions without a callable target) compare equal, non-empty functions compare non-equal.

That said, the `std::function` has also the `operator bool()` ([here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool) is the documentation) that behaves almost the same way and can be used in place of the comparison `my_func == nullptr`.
In particular, it is said that it:

> Checks whether *this stores a callable function target, i.e. is not empty.

I cannot see a case where one can be used and the other does not fit well, so I cannot understand what is the purpose of the `operator==`, apart for the fact that it can be misunderstood and misused the most of the times.

Is there a particular case in which one cannot be used?
Are they interchangeable for they are actually the same thing or it makes sense having two different operators?

Comment: `T* m`, and then `m==nullptr` and `if(m)` to make `std::function` behave like native pointers

Comment: But `m==n` doesn't behave like native pointers...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'm not sure if it makes sense to compare function pointers

Comment: @AngelusMortis: sure it does. Say you have a bunch of them (e.g.: plugins) and you want to remove an entry...

Comment: That's exactly why I consider it counterintuitive, it works only with `nullptr` for `std::function`s, while I'd expect a bit more from an `operator==`. I guess that's also the reason for which it is usually used the wrong way...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath hmmm you're right :)

Comment: @skypjack: well, the bad news is, nobody is going to fix it now.

Comment: The reason for which it works that way is probably due to the fact that a lambda must be assignable to a `std::function`, but such a broken operator does not make sense anyway...

Comment: @Karoly So, the reason is poor design and actually there is no reason, as I suspected? This would make sense indeed.

Comment: The early proposal of `std::function` does not support any comparison operator. (Except declaring without not defining `operator==` for technical reason.) It explicitly say `(in)equality and ordering relations cannot be sensibly defined for function objects.` http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1375.html

Comment: @Nicky Now I'd open another question to ask why they decided then to introduce such a bad definition for that operator, because as it stands today it creates problems and solves none of them. :-)

Comment: @skypjack Which problems does it introduce? It's a sensible definition, and the best one possible.

Comment: @Deduplicator: What it does goes against your intuition... which is usually considered a problem in well designed languages. I know in C++ this was never in focus, but still...

Comment: You are right, unfortunately for one that uses to read the documentation, other nine do not and the expectation of a comparison operator is that it let you compare two objects of the type, while in this case it is defined as a comparison against `nullptr` and nothing more. I know that's the best definition that can be reached, but it's a bit counterintuitive. That's all.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Well, I think in this case itwas a concession to those who love explicitly comparing against `NULL`. And it was for providing as much of the interface as is sensibly and safely possible for template programming. Anyway, comparing functions for equallity is already known to be "interesting", in all but the most controlled situations.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I know, there's *always* a reason. I wasn't implying they had an agenda of creating a confusing language ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48kP_Ssg2eY

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Well, I'm sure even most of the C++ fanatics will concede that if one could redesign it from scratch, there are many quirks and pitfalls not to include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose is simple:

Emulating the interface of a plain function-pointer as well as reasonably possible.

Admittedly, I think they went a bit overboard with that there... even for use in templates.

---

The rationale for only allowing comparison with `nullptr` reflects the [original reason](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1375.html#poisoned_operators) to leave comparisons out completely:

> #### IIIb. Lack of comparison operators
>
> The comparison operators ==, !=, <, >, <=, and >= are not supported by the function object wrapper.
>
> Rationale: (in)equality and ordering relations cannot be sensibly defined for function objects.

The reason is simple: The wrapped target might not support the comparison, might be wrapped differently, or whatever.

There is a way, if you are sure what target the functor wraps, to get at the original arguments:

[`.target_type()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target_type) and [`.target<T>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target).

But you need have quite intimate knowledge what was probably wrapped to make any use of that.

Comment: As in the comments to the question, this is not exactly because `operator==` works only with `nullptr` and I cannot compare two `std::function`s. That's why I consider it counterintuitive.

Comment: @skypjack: The problem with making it work for comparing two `std::function`s is quite simple: Many comparisons would be indeterminate, as whatever was assigned is not comparable. Or might be packaged differently in different parts of the application. Thus that comparison could not be supplied in a satisfactory manner.

Comment: I see. So you confirm that my impression was right: I can use the bool operator whenever someone tries to use the comparison one and invite everybody to avoid using the latter or, at least, carefully read the documentation before to use it, to avoid false expectations.

Comment: Not sure whether related, but this paper mentions "target" kind of stuffs, and has an opinion about `==`. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1667.pdf